# How to format this table using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created the table shown below in LibreOffice:

[image: Table]

I have tried to create this table using HTML5/CSS, this is what I have so far, but I'm struggling to create the table above, using CSS styling.

This is what I have so far:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', san-serif;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border:1px solid #000000;
            }

            table td{
                border:1px solid #000000;
                text-align:center; 
                vertical-align:middle;          
            }           

            table caption {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            th.table-heading {
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
                font-variant: small-caps;
                text-align: left;
                min-width: 100px;
            }

            .vert-center {
              display: table-cell;
              vertical-align: middle;
             }
        </style>


        <table class="foo">
            <caption>
            The caption for the table below goes here
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border: none;">
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>One
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Two
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Three
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Four
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Five
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Six
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Seven
                    <th class="table-heading">column<br>Eight
                </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <!-- summary information about table goes here. -->
                Table footer information here
            </tfoot>    
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jan-80
                    <td class="col1 vert-center">100.0
                    <td class="col2">102.0
                    <td class="col3">103.0
                    <td class="col4">104.5
                    <td class="col5">107.8
                    <td class="col6">106.5
                    <td class="col7">104.7
                    <td class="col8">102.3
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

The JSFiddle for this is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/71fd2yht/1/). As you can see, it looks **nothing** like the intended table. Can someone help with the CSS needed to recreate the table shown in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hows [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/2uzvbwsL/3/)?

I adjusted the height of the table head, removed the breaks from the labels, removed the table border, and gave the individual cells borders.

The new CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', san-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td, thead th:nth-child(:first-child) {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;          
}           

table caption {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

thead tr {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

th.table-heading {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: left;
}

.vert-center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. This is **exactly** what I was trying to do! Could you please explain this CSS rule: `table td, thead th:nth-child(n+2) ` ?

Comment: also, is there any way to reduce the width of the table columns (preferably via CSS)?

Comment: `table td` is every `td` that is descending of a `table`, `, ` allows you to add another selector, `thead th` is every `th` that is descending of a `thead`, `:nth-child(...)` will give you the child at the specified position, `n+2` is an optional formula you can specify which in this case returns all the children skipping the first one.

Comment: And i updated the fiddle, if you want to make the columns thinner just remove the line `min-width: 100px;`